# Vulkan.hpp compiling on one system but not another

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, compilation, vulkan, premake

I have the following generic function:

```
template <typename U>
auto CastVkArray(std::vector<U> &unique_handles)
{
    std::vector<typename U::element_type> handles;
        for(auto &u_handle : unique_handles) handles.push_back(*u_handle);
    return handles;
}
```

The problem is/was that although I thought I instructed premake5 to use the version under a local directory in my project, it was using the system's installed version instead. The version mismatch meant that I was using an old vulkan.hpp header rather than the one I need.
Which I am temporarily using to convert unique handle arrays to non unique arrays. This code compiles just fine on my desktop (arch linux), however on my laptop (ubuntu) I get the error:

```
error: no type named ‘element_type’ in ‘class vk::UniqueHandle<vk::CommandBuffer>’
     std::vector<typename U::element_type> handles;
```

I use premake 5 to generate my build environment and the script hasn't changed between the 2 systems. I checked that all the libraries I am using are the same version, in particualr, I made sure that the vulkan sdk is the same between the 2 computers.

I deleted and rebuilt my code multiple times to test for potential race conditions in compilation (just to see if anything changed), the error is always the same.

The one difference that I have found is that the reported version of premake in arch is 5.0.0-dev but on ubuntu it is 5.0.0-alpha14

But I have not been able to find the dev version on the official github repository of premake.

Comment: crossposted at https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/dgzhps/vulkan_hpp_header_compiles_on_one_system_but_not/

Comment: If you think this is a problem with Premake, it would be nice to see a _minimal_ example of a Premake script which reproduces the problem.